# Incompatible block pointer types SDWebImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

I checked some answers on this, but this is specific to my code, and I cannot get this to work. Any thoughts?

Error starts at

```
completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *...
```

Full code

```
//Load from URL
        NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:image.imageURL];


        SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];

        [manager downloadWithURL:url
                         options:0
                        progress:^(NSUInteger receivedSize, long long expectedSize)
         {
             // progression tracking code
         }
                       completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType)
         {
             if (image)
             {
                 // do something with image
             }
         }];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `SDWebImageManager` header, the method is declared as:

```
- (id<SDWebImageOperation>)downloadWithURL:(NSURL *)url
                                   options:(SDWebImageOptions)options
                                  progress:(SDWebImageDownloaderProgressBlock)progressBlock
                                 completed:(SDWebImageCompletedWithFinishedBlock)completedBlock;
```

`SDWebImageCompetedWithFinishedBlock` is declared like so:

```
typedef void(^SDWebImageCompletedWithFinishedBlock)(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished);
```

So it looks like you're missing the `finished` `BOOL`