# DowloadImageWithURL with SDWebImage

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I am encountering this kind of error on the completion block of `SDWebImage`. My goal is to download the image. Here's my code:

```
let manager: SDWebImageManager = SDWebImageManager.sharedManager()
manager.downloadImageWithURL(NSURL(string: feedDetails.thumbnail), options: [],
    progress: {(receivedSize: Int, expectedSize: Int) -> Void in
    },
    completed: {(image: UIImage, data: NSData, error: NSError, finished: Bool) -> Void in
    }
)
```

**This is the error that I encounter:**

> Cannot convert value of type '(UIImage,NSData,NSError,Bool) -> Void'
>   to expected argument type 'SDWebImageCompletionWithFinishedBlock!'

Comment: try this `SDWebImageDownloader *downloader = [SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader];
[downloader downloadImageWithURL:imageURL
                         options:0
                        progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
                            // progression tracking code
                        }
                       completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {
                            if (image && finished) {
                                // do something with image
                            }
                        }];`

Comment: Maybe this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15484618/6124910 Good luck!

Comment: @Patrick - thanks, this one works

Comment: You´re welcome. If you accept my answer, I´ll appreciate it